# How do I strip custom tags from text in a submitted html form using PHP/Perl?

Tags: php, html, perl, tags, strip

I have a news submission form. I want it to be secure from XSS and the like by stripping all html tags. Then I will convert all other tags with this format

```
[tagname attributes][/closetagname]
```

To this

```
<tagname attributes></closetagname>
```

. 
The question is how do I do the conversion of the tags to this format.

Comment: Are you sure that protects you from XSS? Won't the attack vectors just be `[tagname EXPLOIT]` instead of `<tagname EXPLOIT>` then?

Comment: I think that you be better off Googling for some lightweight BBCODE library or similar where you can control which attributes that will be allowed to prevent you from XSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be secure from XSS just by "*stripping all html tags*" and "*convert all other tags*". Fighting XSS only works by whitelisting *some known* tags (and whitelist *some known* attributes) while blacklisting will always fail.
Here is a [more complete explanation](http://michael-coates.blogspot.com/2008/06/cross-site-scripting-blacklist-vs.html).

A good solution to clean HTML code in PHP is to use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're using PHP, I would think that a combination of the built-in [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip-tags) and the PHP extension [bbcode](http://php.net/bbcode) should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '<tagname attributes></closetagname>';
$clean = str_replace(array('<','>'),array('[',']'), $string);
echo $clean; //[tagname attributes][/closetagname]
?>
```

Of course, this would replace all instances of < and >.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$text = '[tagname attributes][/closetagname]';
$text = preg_replace('/\[([^\[]+?)\]/', '<$1>', $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Assuming you do not get [ and ] inside the tags.

Comment: You can't assume anything when dealing with XSS problems.

Comment: Agree.. I was just looking at this as a pattern matching question. The concept of avoiding XSS by just ruling out HTML tags in itself is vague.